# use qemu dataplane report '.x-data-plane' not found

Tags: qemu

I would like to use qemu dataplane to improve virtual machine io performance.
So I added it to libvirt.xml：

```
<qemu: commandline>
    <qemu: arg value = '- set' />
    <qemu: arg value = 'device.virtio-disk0.x-data-plane = on' />
</qemu: commandline>
```

So I virsh start virtual machine, the results reported the following error:

qemu-kvm: -device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5,drive=drive-virtio-disk0,id=virtio-disk0,bootindex=1: Property '.x-data-plane' not found

What is wrong with this report?  is Compiler qemu lost parameters?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem? It's much easier when people give a detailed context about the problem.

Comment: ok, now details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"x-data-plane" was an experimental option, hence the x- prefix. That means that there was never any guarantee that the option would remain present in new versions of QEMU, or that it would behave the same way from version to version.

In fact, this option was removed in 2015:

```
commit a616fb75c23d768abdc8688d4d6811d3d7eb03e4
Author: Fam Zheng <famz@redhat.com>
Date:   Mon Dec 7 18:59:27 2015 +0800

virtio-blk: Drop x-data-plane option

The official way of enabling dataplane is through the "iothread"
property that references an iothread object created by "-object
iothread".  Since the old "x-data-plane=on" way now even crashes, it's
probably easier to just drop it.
```

So either you're using a QEMU so old it never supported the option, or a QEMU that's new enough that the option was removed, probably the latter. You should find out and use the "official way" to enable dataplane that the commit message talks about.